# How do I spawn villagers that trade for gear with multiple enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm not sure how to summon villagers with trades that can give you items with multiple enchants. I wanted a villager with 50 emeralds for this bow. (Command for bow:

```
 /give @p bow 1 0 {display:{Name:"Gunblade",Lore:["The legendary Gunblade,a ancient relic ","that has the power of a bow and a sword."]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:42076,UUIDLeast:146240}],ench:[{id:17,lvl:3},{id:18,lvl:3},{id:48,lvl:5},{id:49,lvl:2},{id:50,lvl:1},{id:51,lvl:1}],HideFlags:6,Unbreakable:1}.) EDIT: I know how to do this, so you no longer need to post here.
```

I know its a lot, but you just need to tell me how. (All the sources were for 1.7 - 1.8 and only told me how to do it with one enchantment.)

Comment: If you know how to do this, please post it as an answer. Also, if you don't need help anymore, don't EDIT it into a place where you can't even see it normally (not at the end of the command, put it at the end or the beginning of your text!).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to get the commands completed swiftly, try using command generators like [MCStacker](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/), or [Minecraft Tools](http://www.minecraft.tools/).

Answer (score 5):

Here is the full command.

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,Offers:{Recipes:[{rewardExp:0b,maxUses:2147483647,uses:0,buy:{id:emerald,Count:50b},sell:{id:bow,Count:1b,tag:{HideFlags:6,AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:818267,UUIDMost:374333}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Gunblade",Lore:["The legendary Gunblade, an ancient relic","that has the power of a bow and a sword."]},ench:[{id:17,lvl:3},{id:18,lvl:3},{id:48,lvl:5},{id:49,lvl:2},{id:50,lvl:1},{id:51,lvl:1}]}}}]}}
```

all you need to do is basically put the id of the item into the `sell` tag and the rest of the item tag into the `tag` tag.

here is the overview of how the whole NBT is formated:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ 
{
   Profession:0,
   Offers:{
      Recipes:[
         {
            rewardExp:0b,
            maxUses:2147483647,
            uses:0,
            buy:{
               id:emerald,
               Count:50b
            },
            sell:{
               id:bow,
               Count:1b,
               tag:{
                  HideFlags:6,
                  AttributeModifiers:[
                     {
                        AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",
                        Name:"generic.attackDamage",
                        Amount:10,
                        Operation:0,
                        UUIDLeast:818267,
                        UUIDMost:374333
                     }
                  ],
                  Unbreakable:1,
                  display:{
                     Name:"Gunblade",
                     Lore:[
                        "The legendary Gunblade, an ancient relic",
                        "that has the power of a bow and a sword."
                     ]
                  },
                  ench:[
                     {
                        id:17,
                        lvl:3
                     },
                     {
                        id:18,
                        lvl:3
                     },
                     {
                        id:48,
                        lvl:5
                     },
                     {
                        id:49,
                        lvl:2
                     },
                     {
                        id:50,
                        lvl:1
                     },
                     {
                        id:51,
                        lvl:1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```